# What packages are available for creating a Command Line Interface (CLI) in Python?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

What packages are available for creating a Command Line Interface (CLI) in Python? How do they compare with each other in terms of features? I'm thinking of using [Click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/), but I'd like to know what my options are before I commit to it.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you goal is to develop a command-line interface, [Click](http://click.pocoo.org) is definitively a good choice.

- Featurefull,
- Efficient,
- Very well documented,
- Reliable...

Take a look at the [Screencast and Examples](http://click.pocoo.org/5/quickstart/#screencast-and-examples) to have an idea.

Note: the author(s) of this library are also the author(s) of [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).